# How do I select the element's string of descendant?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

How do I select tag "lat" and grab the value "123" base on the "eventid" I want? For example, I want to select `<lle:lat>123</lle:lat>` of `<lle:eventid>ID1</lle:eventid>` without using XPath, just LINQ to XML only

Expected output:

```
123
```

Below is the xml file:

```
    <soapenv:Letter xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" >
        <soapenv:Body xmlns:lle="http://www.aab.org/lifelogevents" >
            <lle:Event>
                <lle:eventid>ID1</lle:eventid>
                <lle:tweet>
                    <lle:text>This is some tweet in my day</lle:text>
                    <lle:location>
                        <lle:lat>123</lle:lat>
                        <lle:long>456</lle:long>
                    </lle:location>
                </lle:tweet>                              
            </lle:Event>
            <lle:Event>
                <lle:eventid>ID2</lle:eventid>
                    <lle:instagram-post-update>
                        <lle:text>This is some status update in my day</lle:text>
                        <lle:location>
                          <lle:lat>789</lle:lat>
                          <lle:long>987</lle:long>
                        </lle:location>
                    </lle:instagram-post-update>
                </lle:Event>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Letter>
```

And this is my C# code so far:

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\JACK\source\repos\LINQ_Learn\LINQ_Learn\xmlFile.xml");
            XNamespace lle = "http://www.aab.org/lifelogevents";
            XNamespace soapenv = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope";


var lati = from data in xmldoc.Descendants(nlle + "Event")
                   where (string)data.Element(nlle + "eventid") == "ID1"
                   select data.Element(nlle + "lat").Value;

        foreach(var lat in lati)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lat);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using Linq to navigate the xml instead. First we get all the descendant "Events", then filter them by the defined "eventid" value and then return their "lat" nodes. `FirstOrDefault()` returns the first match or the null value if none were found. Finally, the `?` symbol serves to return the value of the match only if it isn't null, otherwise it would throw an exception.

```
var lat = xmldoc.Descendants(lle + "Event")
                    .Where(x => x.Element(lle + "eventid").Value == "ID1")
                        .Descendants(lle + "lat")
                            .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```